# How can I solve "only use .str accessor with string values"

Tags: python, pandas

I have checked similar solutions but couldn't solve what I want to do.

When I try to execute the following pandas operation, I am experiencing this error. `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2,3], 'Test': ['(BOB,)', '(Tom,BOB)', '(AAA,BBB, CCC)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

df

```
ID    Test
1    (BOB,)
2   (Tom,BOB)
3   (AAA,BBB, CCC)
```

```
df['Test'] = df['Test'].str.strip('(,)').str.split(',')
```

`df.dtypes` for column `Test` is `string`.

The expected out put is:
df

```
ID    Test
1    [BOB,]
2   [Tom,BOB]
3   [AAA,BBB, CCC]
```

After that I will use multiple operations such as `df.explode()` to get what I want.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Why are you using str.strip? Isn't it just 'strip()'?

Comment: @Ismail Hafeez because OP is woking on a `Series`

Comment: Ah, ok.. Nevermind then.

Comment: @Hiwot can you post a part of your dataframe or post a part of 'Test' series

Comment: @AnuragDabas Can you check the edit?

Comment: @Hiwot Your code working fine and giving a list of splited values...............I think you are having tuple in Test columns that's why you are getting this error you can verify this by typing:-  `type(df.loc[0,'Test'])`

Comment: I have more than 100K rows. and Yes, it is says "tuple". How can I manage that?

Comment: @Hiwot can you write your expected output?

Comment: @AnuragDabas Can you check the updated question?

Comment: @Hiwot yeah...check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataframe:-

```
d = {
    'ID': [1, 2,3], 
    'Test': [('BOB',),('Tom','BOB'),('AAA','BBB','CCC')]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

You are getting this error because the values inside your **"test"** column are of tuple type so if you want to convert that tuple in string then use `astype()` method:-

```
df['Test']=df['Test'].astype(str)
```

Now its of type string you can cross verify by this:-

```
type(df.loc[0,'Test'])
```

Comment: With this particular example it works perfect. But when I take this to my data (>100K rows). I am still getting same error. ```AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!``` I have converted the tuple to list but same error.

Comment: This is happening because Its a `list` and you can't use `.str` accessor with a `list` unless you iterate over it....what you want to do with this list? can you add your final expected result in your question?

Comment: But is there a way to convert tuple type to string without losing combination values? For example this (BOB,) is tuple type when I check it. Is there a way to change all column values to string type?

Comment: @Hiwot Update my answer...kindly have a look....btw if this answer helped you then feel free to accept this answer